# How to add an image to a GitHub static page using Jekyll

Tags: github, static-pages

I am creating a portfolio using GitHub static pages and I want to display some images of projects completed and finding it difficult to do that. I know the syntax for image display but what I do not seem to get here is where to place image on GitHub and use the path to display it.

syntax for image display

```
![Alternate image text](image source here)
```

Comment: Please provide the tool you are using to generate your static site (etc. Hugo, Jekyll, Gatsby etc.). You should be able to just pass the relative link to the file `[Great Image](./images/great-image.png)`.

Comment: i am using  Jekyl what i don't understand is where to upload the image before providing the absolute link

Comment: @ade-desmund I'm not familiar with that platform, but in general you should just be able to add the image to the github repo and pass the relative path to your markdown file.

Comment: i have done that and passing the path all i get is a broken image file not displaying

Comment: this is the path am using  but i do not get any image https://github.com/desmond75/desmond75.github.io/blob/master/img/mobil.PNG

Comment: try this: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#images `![Here is the alt text](https://github.com/desmond75/desmond75.github.io/blob/master/img/mobil.PNG "Here is the Title text")`